# Using parindent within the longtable environment

Tags: tables, longtable, xetex

Here is a simple test case of the problem I'm having:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{longtable}

\begin{document}

\begin{longtable}{p{2in}|p{5in}}
  foo & \parindent=1in bar \\
\end{longtable}

\begin{tabular}{p{2in}|p{5in}}
  foo & \parindent=1in bar \\
\end{tabular}

\end{document}
```

This produces the following output

[image: this output]

(I'm using "XeTeX, Version 3.1415926-2.2-0.9995.2 (TeX Live 2009/Debian)" on Ubuntu 11.04). There are two problems with this:

1. There are different default indentation settings in `tabular` and `longtable`
2. In the `longtable` environment, I can't seem to redefine the indentation using `\parindent`

I'm not so much concerend with #1 if I can solve #2.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer for 2.

Just force the indent: `& \parindent=1in \indent bar`

(Note: Questions of this kind will be answered quickly and properly by the bunch of experts on TeX.SX.)

Comment: Thanks for your Note at the end, I didn't know about that site. I asked my first question on TeX.SX today and got several informative answers within a couple hours.